# Can't connect two Bluetooth devices at the same time

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a keyboard and a mouse in Ubuntu 20.04 but I just can't get it done.

Tried with `bluetoothctl` and `blueman` but no results. I have the devices trusted and paired but I can only connect one at a time, can't connected both.
I have dual-boot, in Windows 10 everything works but in Ubuntu 20.04 just one device at a time.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling Wi-Fi, then connecting both bluetooth devices.

Comment: @PJSingh with the wifi off, after several attempts I managed to connect both devices but one only works :(

Comment: It was worth a try. I know some newer chips have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth combined, and both functions interfere with each other (unless you are using the proprietary Windows drivers). You should edit your question and share your hardware info. Perhaps someone has the same chip and can suggest a solution.

Comment: @RodrigoLuna were you able to fix it? I can't connect my earphones and keyboard simultaneously.

Comment: I also have this problem. Windows 10 works fine, while Ubuntu 20.04 failed to connect multiple bluetooth devices. I have RTL8192EE wifi+bt chip on Asus K401U

Comment: On other forums, there are also other people who have the same problem with RTL8822BE: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=341622 https://forum.manjaro.org/t/connect-two-bluetooth-devices-simultaneously/25259

Comment: Based on Realtek's website, RTL8192EE and RTL8822BE seem to have the same windows driver. Perhaps the multiple device connection is not supported on the linux driver? https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8192ee-software https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8822be-software

Answer (score 3):

Today I also wanted to connect my Logitech keyboard to Ubuntu 20.04 version. Because the headphone was already connected, I couldn't connect the keyboard.

First I tried to connect keyboard and then headphones. In that situation the keyboard worked but not the Bluetooth headphone, so I opened the Bluetooth's `main.conf` file....

```
sudo vi /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

and then changed the section "**MultiProfile=multiple**" from "off" (the default value) to "multiple", and save the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ---> :wq --> <kbd>Enter</kbd>] like the following:

[image]

After that just try to connect both devices (you can try via restarting once).

Comment: It didn't work for me. Are you sure it worked for you?

Comment: Also didn't fix the issue for me

Comment: thanks a lot. this worked for me for both keyboard and airpods at a time.

Comment: This worked for me, and required `sudo service bluetooth restart` after the edit to take effect.