# Unable to connect to multiple bluetooth devices at the same time

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I have a bluetooth keyboard and headset. I can only connect one of them at a time to my laptop. Both can connect to my android phone at the same time (plus my mouse as well), however only the one I connect first to my Ubuntu install works correctly.

When turning on, and trying to connect to, the other bluetooth device I have noticed that my already connected device connection stops working. My headphones do not receive any audio and disconnecting and reconnecting does not work. Have to restart to get back audio. My headphones do not give me the disconnecting tone, but my laptop is unable to connect to it, saying that the connection has failed.

I edited the main.conf file to have MultiProfile=multiple, but that has had no effect as far as I can tell as instructed in this [question asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354909/cant-connect-two-bluetooth-devices-at-the-same-time)

If there are any commands I should run to provide more details please let me know I'm just an average newbie user. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect two Bluetooth devices at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354909/cant-connect-two-bluetooth-devices-at-the-same-time)

Comment: @user68186 I already tried that solution and mentioned it in my post, unfortunately that hasn't solved my problem